# How to use Eclipse Memory Analyser Tool (MAT) for analysing a hashmap

Tags: java, android, eclipse, memory, android-memory

I am facing a **memory leak**. So, I captured a `heap dump` for my application, and am trying to analyse it using **Memory Analyser Tool (MAT)**. I clicked on Heap Dump Overview option in the menu of `hprof file`. Then , clicked on `Class Histogram`. It showed me a list of all objects, grouped by class, taking up the maximum meory. One of which is my cutom hashmap. Now, I want to analyse the entries of this `hashmap`.

Any idea how I can do so ? If I click on the custom hashmap name, then click on `List Objects->with incoming references`, it just shows list of all objects in the `hashmap` & the hierarchy by which these objects was created, & **not the actual key-value pairs for the hashmap entries**.

P.S. My custom Hashmap:

```
private Hashmap<Integer, TextCache> mCache;

class TextCache{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    int left;
    int right;
    int keyCode;
}
```

Comment: Not related to MAT, but what I do is isolate where and when the leak occurs by using Java VisualVM (it's jvisualvm.exe in your java bin) and debugging line by line, function by function. :) With it, I can trace when and where the memory usage spiked.

Comment: @praveen *Please* do not do edits that simply make words bold.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Sure. thanks for suggestion. I will take care about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, I was trying to view the hprof file from `Java/Debug` Perspective. When I switch to `Memory Analysis` perspective, I could view the details of all objects, including key-value pairs for hashmap entries, in an `Inspector` -> `Attributes` window towards the left.

Edit: "key" attribute of the hashmap entries are still not visible. Only attributes of my custom hashmap entry object, which is the "value" part are visible. So, what I did is, for testing purpose, I put the key attribute (which is an integer), in the custom hashmap entry object, to be able to view it from the `Inspector` -> `Attributes` from the `Memory Analysis` perspective.

```
class TextCache{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    int left;
    int right;
    int keyCode;
    int key; // this is actually the key used to insert objects of TextCache into the hashmap.
}
```

If anybody finds out, how to directly view the "key" part from the hprof file, it would be great.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the perspective thing :)
i was looking for that.